# Unseen Theorem Based on Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

In the figure, ABCD is a square and PEFG is a rectangle. If PD=PE, prove that square ABCD and the rectangle PEFG are equal in area.[image]

Here $\triangle PCG$ similar to $\triangle PCD$.
$$\frac{PG}{PC}=\frac{CG}{CD}=\frac{PC}{PD}$$

Now, how should I complete the rest?

Comment: Are we allowed to use Pythagoras theorem? Or only similarity?

Comment: #N.S.JOHN. It's not a compulsion to use similarity. You can use Pythagoras Theorem too

Comment: According to your similarity equality $PG.PD$=Area of rectangle=$PC.PC$ Which is wrong.

Comment: #N.S. JOHN. The same I got so I was confused about that.

Comment: Get similar triangle CDG into the equation. Then CD/PD = DG/CD and Area of square =$CD^2=PD*DG=PE*DG \ne $ Area of rectangle.  Your statement isn't true.  (Someone please double check my work.)

Comment: @Fleeblood, I too think that the statement is wrong.

Comment: $right angled \triangle PCG $ with $D \bot PG$ forms a special configuration of similar triangles. The standard result derived is $CD^2 = (PD)(DG)$. The LHS is the area of the square and the RHS is the area of the rectangle.

Comment: @fleablood How did you get $CDG$ and $CDP$ simillar?

Comment: @tatan they are two right triangles that share a second angle in common.  So they share the third angle in common.  So they share all angles in common.

Comment: @Mick but (PD)(DG) is **NOT** the area of the rectangle given.  The rectangle given is PE FG which has area (PE)(PG) = (PD)(PD + DG) = $PD^2$ + (PD)(DG) > (PD)(DG) = $CD^2$ = Area of ABCD.  So the statement is not true.  The area of the rectangle is bigger than the area of the square by ($PD^2$).

Comment: If they had drawn an H on line EF so that EPDH were a rectangle/square.  What *would* be true is that area square ABCD = area rectangle HDGF.  Which would be a nice excercise.  (area of Square = $CD^2 = (PD)(DG) = (PE)(DG) = (DH)DG$ = area of rectangle).

Comment: @fleablood You have answered your own question through your last sentence.

Comment: @mick what question? I didn't ask any question.